# Vstack of two arrays with same number of rows gives an error

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of shape (29, 10) and a list of 29 elements and I want to end up with an array of shape (29,11)

I am basically converting the list to a numpy array and trying to vstack, but it complain about dimensions not being the same.

Toy example

```
a = np.zeros((29,10))
a.shape
(29,10)

b = np.array(['A']*29)
b.shape
(29,)

np.vstack((a, b))
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Dimensions do actually match, why am I getting this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `np.hstack`.

```
np.hstack((a, b.reshape(-1,1)))
```

Moreover `b` must be 2-dimensional, that's why I used a `reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to append a 1D array to a 2D array.
Also, for the dimension you've given for b, you are probably looking for hstack.
 Try this:

```
a = np.zeros((29,10))
a.shape
(29,10)

b = np.array(['A']*29)[:,None] #to ensure 2D structure
b.shape
(29,1)

np.hstack((a, b))
```

If you do want to vertically stack, you'd need this:

```
a = np.zeros((29,10))
a.shape
(29,10)

b = np.array(['A']*10)[None,:] #to ensure 2D structure
b.shape
(1,10)

np.vstack((a, b))
```